Syntax of *heptaplomeres*
The title of a book by 16th century writer Joannes Bodinus, Colloquium heptaplomeres de rerum sublimium arcanis abditis, which Wikipedia translates as "Colloquium of the Seven about Secrets of the Sublime," contains a striking word, heptaplomeres.
I have not yet found this word in any dictionary. What is its dictionary form? Is it a noun? Singular or plural? Genitive or something else? What exactly is it's grammatical function here?

I'm assuming the first element is ἑπταπλόος 'sevenfold', but I don't know about the second one. It looks like a nominative plural.

Something to do with μέρος? “Sevenfold-parted”?

@MartinKochanski: I think so too. And the ending -ες is neuter singular in a certain group of adjectives.

@Cerberus, Do you think heptaplomeres is a neuter adjective modifying colloquium?

@Figulus: Yes, also because I couldn't parse the title otherwise. But I can't prove it.

An adjective on -meres made me think it must be from μέρος "part". And I wouldn't be surprised if an adjective like that were of the ψευδής type, which has a neuter singular on -ές (Latinised -es). Then it agrees with colloquium.
Similar adjectives are penthemimeres "of five half-parts" and hephthemimeres "of seven half-parts".

Nam et initium hexametri statim inuenias, et anacreontion protinus colon efficies, et si uelis trimetron, et quod duobus pedibus et parte πενθημιμερές a Graecis dicitur, et haec omnia in tribus uersibus: ...
— Quintilianus, Institutio Oratoria 9.4.78.

Loeb translation: "...where you can at once find the beginning of a hexameter, and then make out an Anacreonteion and, if you choose, a trimeter, and what the Greeks call a penthēmimeres (comprising two feet and a half), and all this within three lines!".
You can see that all the other things in the enumeration are also neuter: colon, trimetron, quod (agreeing with πενθημιμερές).
Some more quotations I leave for the reader to compare:

Monometrum hypercatalectum, quod penthemimeres sive ancration appellatur, ut est apud Euripiden, ter peribimus.
— Fragmenta Bobiensia, De Versibus 620.3.


initium versus, ut puta 'vota Minerva iuvat', penthemimeres est
— Idem, De Structuris 628.30.


Has autem leges heroicus omnis habebit.
cum post duos pedes relicta syllaba est,
si plenum absolvet verbi vel nominis instar,
orationis ista vel quae pars erit,
hoc πενθημιμερές medium de quinque vocatur:
hanc et tomen dixere.
— Terentianus Maurus, De Litteris, De Syllabis, De Metris 1669.

